# Calling javascript function and also hitting a link in same anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, anchor, jquery-cookie

Is this possible to call a javascript funciton(save cookies() here for example)before redirecting to a new page(sample.html in my example).

I need to save cookies before i navigate to new page.

```
a href=/dashboard/sample.html onclick="savecookies()"
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do it via JQuery. 
You can set any anchor link with a class

```
<a href="#someUrl" class="navigator (other class)" >MyAwesomeLink</a>
```

Then in Jquery

```
  $(".navigator").click(function(e){
     var url = $(this).attr('href').replace('#','');
    /** Save your cookie stuff here **/ 
    window.location.href = "PATH"+url;
    e.preventDefault();
    }
```

You can even "unprevent" and let the href without "#" simbol but i prefer this way IMHO it's better if you handle it.

Answer (score 3):

use something like this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
   saveCookie();  // save cookies
   document.location.href = "sample.html";  // forward user to new page

   return false;  // ignore default src of anchor
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a single function and paste the code for saving cookies and then at the end of the function paste the code for navigation.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to redirect through JS code, just grab the link and bind a click function to it which executes your function and then returning true;

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function() {
       //alert('clicked');
       saveCookie();
       return true;
    });
})
```